# streaming rails (in upload)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, streaming

I'm wondering if it's possible to stream content to a rails app ?
Something like send_data but for the upload ?

Thanks !

Comment: what do you mean as "upload streaming"? if it is just file uploading, make a file input field in form, and uploaded temporary file can be accessed through params. if not, please give a link to example.

Comment: I mean to stream a content to a rails app and process each chunk of data on the fly.

Comment: can you please give a link to example? the problem is that HTTP prorocol is expected to give answer only after receiving the full request. I think the only case to make this - partial data sending through ajax, so each request will post next portion of data, and rails will process it depending on session.

Comment: I don't have a link yet. I think rails is not the right thing to do that so I did a little node.js server to get a streaming content (HTTP/1.1 and Transfer-Encoding: chunked) which works perfectly ! Thanks for your responses :)

Answer (score -2):

Do you need that:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/266-http-streaming
?

Comment: This is to stream content from a rails app but I need to stream content to a rails app. Thanks anyway !